# 'Sequence contains no elements', happening?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

It's a WINDOWSFORM

I have combobox, I use this code for auto textboxvalue but I receive this error

> Sequence contains no elements

```
private void cmbOfficeNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork())

    if (cmbOfficeNumber.SelectedValue.ToString() != null)
    {
        txtOfficeName.Text = db.OfficeRepository.GetOfficeNamebyNumber(cmbOfficeNumber.Text);

    }
}
```

And this is my repository code

```
public string GetOfficeNamebyNumber(string officeNumber)
{
    return db.Office.First(g => g.OfficeNumber == officeNumber).OfficeName;
}
```

EDIT: When using

```
return db.Office.FirstOrDefault(g => g.OfficeNumber == officeNumber).OfficeName;
```

I receive a different error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Change to ``return db.Office.FirstOrDefault(g => g.OfficeNumber == officeNumber)?.OfficeName;`` but you need to manage null values after return. you have this comportment because the value of``officeNumber`` not exist in base.

Comment: @madreflection i check it before, and i check all ways... but my problem is not solve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If First() results in

```
Sequence contains no elements
```

That means the condition in the lambda expression resulted in no hits. Because First requires you to have atleast one match.

If FirstOrDefault().Property results in

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

It means that the lambda expression resulted in no hits, and it returns a default value of the return type. In the case of a reference object it will be null. You then tried to access a property of null which causes the exception.

Simply put. Your problem is that your comparison is returning no hits.

You need to insert a fail safe for this to not crash

Something like:

```
public string GetOfficeNamebyNumber(string officeNumber)
{
    var result = db.Office.FirstOrDefault(g => g.OfficeNumber == officeNumber);

    if(result == null)
        return string.Empty;

    return result.OfficeName;
}
```

This can also be shortend to

```
public string GetOfficeNamebyNumber(string officeNumber)
{
    var result = db.Office.FirstOrDefault(g => g.OfficeNumber == officeNumber);

    return result?.OfficeName ?? string.Empty;
}
```

Or even

```
public string GetOfficeNamebyNumber(string officeNumber)
{
    return db.Office.FirstOrDefault(g => g.OfficeNumber == officeNumber)?.OfficeName ?? string.Empty;
}
```

I hope this step by step explanation gives you the information you need to solve the problem.

Comment: very very very very thanks you big help to me, after 10 days i solve my problem, i check ton of code and filter and now my problem have solved

Comment: @AliZangeneh No problem! Glad I could help

Comment: im new on c# and i have ton of question :) i know how to work , but i dont know how write my code in c# ( im good in VB )

Comment: @AliZangeneh - I changed to c# from VB many many years ago. Other than XML literals I find c# a better language to program in. You'll get there.

Comment: @Enigmativity me too bro but this is hard for me...but i know i can learn c# soon bcs i understand program and code